# Añadir a favoritos (Web con php y mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy haciendo una web con php y mysql en la que muestro una galeria de imagenes con animales, y esos animales estan registrados en una tabla en la bd. Para ello he creado una tabla llamada 'favorito' la cual tiene el id de usuario y del animal. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se guarde en la tabla de favorito el id de usuario que lo guarda y el animal que ha guardado? [image: Así tengo estructurada la BD]

Código en el que muestro la información detallada del animal y donde se le puede dar a favorito.

```
<?php
session_start();
    require ('index.php');
    require "navegacion.php";
    
    // Si existe nombre y id lo obtiene a través del get
if (isset($_GET['nombre']) && isset($_GET['id'])) :
    // Obtenemos el nombre y el id
    $nombre_perro = $_GET['nombre']; 
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    // Obtienes datos desde la nueva función
    // Instanciamos el objeto
    $obj = new Animales();
    // Llamamos a la funcion
    $datos = $obj->visualizarById($id);
endif;

//si pulsa el boton de favorito se llama a la funcion añadir y se añade a favorito
if (isset($_POST['fav']) && isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) : 
    $addfav = $obj->add();

 elseif (isset($_POST['fav']) && !isset($_SESSION['usuario'])):
        header("location:login.php"); 
    
endif;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssanimales.css">
 
</head>
<body>

    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div>     
                    <?php
        // Muestra los datos
        echo '<pre>';
  
        
        ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $datos->img;?>" alt="alt"/>
                    <?php echo $datos->nombre ?><br/>
                    <?php echo $datos->edad ?><br/>
                   <?php echo $datos->sexo ?><br/>
                    <?php echo $datos->tamanyo ?><br/>
                     <?php echo $datos->esterilizado ?>
                 
                    <?php echo $datos->raza ?><br/>
                    <?php echo $datos->descripcion ?><br/>
                    <?php
     
        ?>      <form name="boton_fav" method="POST">
                 <input class="button" type="submit" name="fav" value="Añadir" />
                 
                 
        </form>
                   </div>
   
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

</body>
    </html>
```

Código con las clases donde realizo las consultas a la BD

```
class Animales {

    public function visualizar() {

        require 'config.php';
        //realiza una consulta a la tabla animal
        $registros = $base->query("SELECT a.id,a.nombre,a.edad,a.sexo,a.tamanyo,a.esterilizado,a.tipo_animal 
    as 'tipo',p.nombre as 'protectora',r.tipo as 'raza',i.url as 'img'
FROM animal a 
INNER JOIN imagenes i 
    on i.id=(select i2.id from imagenes i2 where i2.id_animal=a.id limit 1)
    INNER JOIN raza r on (a.raza=r.id)
    INNER JOIN protectora p on (p.id=a.id_protectora);")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //almacenamos un array de obj

        return $registros;
    }

    public function visualizarById(int $id) {
        require 'config.php';
        $registros = $base->prepare("SELECT a.id,a.nombre,a.edad,a.sexo,a.tamanyo,a.esterilizado,a.tipo_animal
    as 'tipo',p.nombre as 'protectora',r.tipo as 'raza',i.url as 'img'
        FROM animal AS a 
  INNER JOIN imagenes AS i on i.id=(select i2.id from imagenes i2 where i2.id_animal=a.id limit 1)
  INNER JOIN raza AS r on (a.raza=r.id)
  INNER JOIN protectora AS p on (p.id=a.id_protectora) 
       WHERE a.id = :id");

        //Le pasamamos el parametro :id
        $registros->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        // Ejecutamos la sentencia (consulta la BD)
        $registros->execute();
        $resultado = $registros->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $resultado;
    }

    //añade animal a favorito 
    public function add() {

        
        require 'config.php';
        
        if (isset($_POST['fav'])) {

             $id_usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
             $id_animal = $id;
        }
        $add = $base->prepare("insert into favorito (id_animal, id_usuario) VALUES(?,?)");
        
      

        $add->bindValue(1, $id_animal, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $add->bindValue(2, $id_usuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $add->execute();
    }
```

Código donde inicio la variable de sesión

```
   public function login() {
        require 'config.php';

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email= :email AND password= :password";

        $resultado = $base->prepare($sql);

        $email = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["email"]));

        $password = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));

        $resultado->bindValue(":email", $email);

        $resultado->bindValue(":password", $password);

        $resultado->execute();

        $numero_registro = $resultado->rowCount(); //creamos variable

        if ($numero_registro != 0) { //si el usuario si existe en nuestra bd inicia sesion
            session_start();

            $_SESSION["usuario"] = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //almacenamos en la variable super global sesion el login del usuario

            /*           if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){

              } */

            header("location:portada.php"); //redirige a menu de users registrados si esta todo correcto
        } else {
            echo 'datos incorrectos';
            header("location:login.php"); //redirige de nuevo al login si el usuario se equivoca en los datos
        }
    }
```

No sé si lo que llevo hecho está bien, sé que al menos la forma en la que referencio al animal el cual se está viendo la información está mal. ¿Cómo puedo referenciarlo?

Comment: Dónde tienes disponible el ID del usuario? Cómo es la página que muestra los animales? Esencialmente le envías esos datos a un método en tu modelo y los guardas, pero pues... el resto es clarividencia :/

Comment: @Alfabravo acabo de actualizar la pregunta

Comment: Mediante PHP vas bien encamino, aunque te falta pasar en el formulario el **id** del animal, para obtenerlo en tu funcion **add()**, por ejemplo no veo como obtienes ```$id``` aquí ```$id_animal = $id;```, podrías hacer un ```return false``` o ```true``` desde tu función, si la sentencia se ejecutó, y según el booleana o recargas la página para su efecto o lanzas algún mensaje de error. Quedaría más dinámico usando JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
//si pulsa el boton de favorito se llama a la funcion añadir y se añade a favorito
if (isset($_POST['fav']) && isset($_SESSION['usuario']) && isset($_GET['id'])) :
    // le enviamos a add el id de usuario y el del animal
    if($obj->add($_SESSION['usuario'],$_GET['id'])):
            header("Refresh:0")
    endif;    
 elseif (isset($_POST['fav']) && !isset($_SESSION['usuario'])):
        header("location:login.php"); 
    
endif;
```

**nota:** puedes hacer el **require("conexion.php")** al principio de tu archivo antes de class y ya puedes quitarlo de todos los metodos y funcionaria exactamente igual..

y en tu clase quedaria asi:

```
// recibimos el paramentos id_anima y id_usuario
public function add(int $id_animal,int $id_user):bool{

    $add = $base->prepare("insert into favorito (id_animal, id_usuario) VALUES(?,?)");
    $add->bindValue(1, $id_animal, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $add->bindValue(2, $id_user, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    if($add->execute()){
        return true
    }
    return false;
}
```

si utilizas una version menor a php7

```
public function add($id_animal,$id_user){
```

te recomiendo agregar un campo **id** a **favorito** para que tengas un id unico al cual hacer referencia en caso que al usuario ya no le guste o quierea eliminarlo

Comment: me dice esto en la linea de la función ncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Animales::add(),

Comment: en que linea exactamente lo marca??

Comment: public function add (int $id_animal,int $id_user):bool{ aquí

Comment: agrege una modificacion en mi post por version creo que es eso

Comment: me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: pregunta: $_SESSION['usuario'] contiene el id del usuario o el nombre? en caso de que sea el nombre crear un $_SESSION['id'] asignalo en el inicio de session y vuelve a iniciar session para que se carge!

Comment: la variable sesion (ubicada en el login) tiene la consulta a la bd la cual recupera los datos del usuario. en que parte del codigo creo la variable de sesion con id? en la funcion que tiene el login?. acabo de editar la publicación y muestro como tengo la variable de usuario

Comment: le estas pasando el fetch completo por ende debes acceder a la posicion del id. seria $_SESSION['usuario'][0] que seria la posicion 1 o editas dependiendo de la posicion en tu query!